# Трудности с постановкой запятой в сложносочинённом предложении

Tags: пунктуация, ссп

**"Говоришь по-русски(,) или ты русский?"**

Тут же одно сказуемое глагольное, а другое выражено существительным. Нужна ли запятая? Мне кажется, что нужна.

Answer (score 3):

**Запятая НЕ нужна, так как оба предложения вопросительные.**

Запятая в сложносочинённом предложении НЕ ставится, если:

***4) части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения; объединяющей здесь оказывается единая интонация, в побудительных предложениях могут быть и общие частицы.
Например: Где будет собрание и кто его председатель? – общая вопросительная интонация; Как тихо вокруг и как чисто звездное небо!  – общая восклицательная интонация; Пусть светит солнце и птицы поют! – общая частица; объединяющим элементом может быть и союз: Кончились майские холода, стало тепло, и зажухла черемуха. Зато наметились бутоны рябины и расцветает сирень (Пришв.).***[Здесь](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/287-znakip)